# What is the deal with $p$-value when generating Pearson's $r$ correlation coefficient?

Tags: correlation

I know how to generate Pearson's $r$ correlation values in Excel and in R.

I understand the meaning of the value as it ranges from $-1<r<1$

I also understand hypothesis tests, confidence intervals, and $p$-value.  ($p$ = the probability that this outcome was due to random chance or natural variation, and null hypothesis is true)

However, I am having trouble making the connection between Pearson's $r$ correlation and $p$-value.  In a hypothesis test, there is some element of chance of the variation of outcomes (like coin flips).  But, in a regression, it is based on actual data points.  So what does p-value mean in this context?  The odds that the data points are just clustered due to random chance?  Is this directly based on sample size? I ask because I wonder how would a formula know anything about the variability of discrete data points (such as selling price and mileage of a car).

So, for an r value, the p-value is based on sample size?
What I don't understand is that p-value seems to answer a binary question: Is there an effect or not?
But for a correlation coefficient, there isn't a yes/no question being asked.

If I get an r = .8, and p-value of .20, what does that mean?
It means there is a 20% chance that the correlation of .8 is not true?
But, then what IS true? r=.7 ? r=.6?

Or is the rule of thumb that you can only use the r value, regardless of number, if p < .05 ?

If I get an r = .1, and p-value of .0001, what does that mean? 
We are very confident there is a very weak correlation? (How ironic?)

If I get an r = .5, and p-value of .0001, what does that mean? 
We are very confident there is a moderate correlation?

If I get an r = .5, and p-value of .3, what does that mean? 
It means there is a 30% chance that there is a moderate correlation of .5 ?

Comment: Im afraid , your understanding of the p value is not generally correct, which may be where the question originates. For the actual question, what null hypothesis about the correlation for which you need to understand p do you have in mind? The  usual $\rho=0$? Or any other?

Comment: Also, you should start accepting and upvoting aswers to your question. This encourages answers.

Comment: So, for an r value, the p-value is based on sample size?
What I don't understand is that p-value seems to answer a binary question: Is there an effect or not?
But for a correlation coefficient, there isn't a yes/no question being asked. 

If I get an r = .8, and p-value of .20, what does that mean?
It means there is a 20% chance that the correlation of .8 is not true?
But, then what IS true? r=.7 ? r=.6? 

Or is the rule of thumb that you can only use the r value, regardless of number, if p < .05 ?

Comment: If I get an r = .1, and p-value of .0001, what does that mean? 
We are very confident there is a very weak correlation? (How ironic?)

If I get an r = .5, and p-value of .0001, what does that mean? 
We are very confident there is a moderate correlation? 

If I get an r = .5, and p-value of .3, what does that mean? 
It means there is a 30% chance that there is a moderate correlation of .5 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Fixed/improved, based on the feedback from @Momo and @whuber]

I believe that in the context of regression the *relationship* between *$p$-value* and *Pearson's correlation coefficient* is the following: $p$-value can be interpreted as *probability* that correlation (coefficient), determined in a random sampling-based experiment, is the same or larger than the one, determined from the observed data, **provided that the null hypothesis is true**. In other words, I think that $p$-value in this context is related to *hypothesis testing*, where hypotheses themselves are *correlation-based*, as follows:

\begin{multline}
\shoveleft{H_0: \text{correlation (of the underlying data-generation process) is zero;}}\\
\shoveleft{H_A: \text{the correlation is not zero.}}
\end{multline}

Then, the situation IMHO boils down to the following *traditional hypothesis testing interpretation*. If $p$-value is small (less than arbitrarily selected *significance level* $\alpha$, usually equal to 0.05), then you can reject the null hypothesis ("determined correlation is statistically significant"), and, if $p$-value is greater than $\alpha$, than you fail to reject the null ("the correlation is not statistically significant").

In regard to a relationship between $p$-value and sample size $N$, the following formulae present the relationship in question in a mathematical form.

*Fisher transformed test statistic* of $r$ (aka $z$) is defined as $T(r) = artanh(r)$.

For a *bivariate normal distribution*, $z$'s *standard error* depends on *sample size* $N$, as follows:

\begin{align}
SE(T(r)) \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{N - 3}}
\end{align}

Moreover, since the test statistic is approximately normal,

\begin{align}
\frac{T(r)}{SE(T(r))} \approx N(0,1) \text{ and } \lim_{N\to\infty} SE(T(r)) = 0
\end{align}

so the standard error in the denominator is getting increasingly smaller for increasingly larger $N$.

P.S. You may also find the following two answers relevant and useful: [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/94574/31372) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/49173/31372).

Comment: The hypotheses as currently written are not valid hypotheses in a standard testing setting.  I would therefore like to suggest they should be formulated differently.  The null is that the correlation coefficient (of the underlying data-generation process) is zero, *not* "due to random chance"; the alternative is that it is not zero.

Comment: @Momo & whuber: Thank you for your suggestions and corrections. As I work on learning/improving my knowledge of statistics, your feedback is very valuable not only to the OP, but to me as well. I will try to read a bit more and then consolidate the feedback from both of you and update my answer to the best of my (current) knowledge. I appreciate your comments!

Comment: @aleksander Great, I'm sure it will become a good answer.

Comment: You write that the p-value is the "probability that correlation (coefficient), determined in a random sampling-based experiment, is the same or larger than the one". Please re-read and amend this obvious falsehood.

Comment: @DWin: Please feel free to fix whatever the erroneous information this (or any other answer) contains. Just make sure to provide relevant references. I will be more than happy to learn from you.